Apache Netbeans Installation on Ubuntu 22.04: Problem with verification of downloaded file
Apache netbeans installation on Ubuntu 22.04:
I am trying to install latest version of apache netbeans. I downloaded the Ubuntu version from the link:
https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/netbeans/netbeans-installers/23/apache-netbeans_23-1_all.deb#verify
The “Verify the integrity of the files” section on the above link says:

Verify the integrity of the files ¶
It is essential that you verify the integrity of the downloaded file
using the PGP signature ( .asc file) or a hash ( .md5 or .sha* file).
Please read Verifying Apache Software Foundation Releases for more
information on why you should verify our releases.
Verifying Apache Software Foundation Releases
Home page of The Apache Software Foundation

The PGP signature can be verified using PGP or GPG. First download the KEYS as well as the asc signature file for the relevant distribution. Make sure you get these files from the main distribution site, rather than from a mirror. Then verify the signatures using (given 2 commands).
But when I am executing :
“% gpg --import KEYS”
om my ‘$” prompt , I am getting the error:
 $gpg --import KEYS

gpg: can't open 'KEYS': No such file or directory

gpg: Total number processed: 0Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.
